# How do I get template variable in Angular from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, dom

I am working on a project where the backend API has two end points for each view:
- one that sends me the view structure in JSON format
- one that sends me the data with which to populate the view generated from the format.

I have a directive that generates the html tags directly based on the format JSON.
Here is the directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamicTag]'
})
export class DynamicTagDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private vcf: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }
  private _tag: string;
  private _needUpdate: boolean = false;

  @Input('dynamicTag')
  set tag(t: string) {
    this._tag = t;
    this._needUpdate = true;
    this.vcf.clear();
    let template = this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (template) {

  this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode.removeChild(template);
    }
    this.vcf.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this._needUpdate) {
      this.updateTemplate();
      this._needUpdate = false;
    }
  }

  private updateTemplate() {
    let template = this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (template) {
      let r = document.createElement(this._tag);
      r.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
      console.log(template);
      console.log(template.innerHTML);
          this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode.replaceChild(r, template);
    }
  }
}
```

And I am using it in a template like so:

```
<span *dynamicTag="row?.attribute">
    <strong class="ml-1">{{ selectedUser?.nom }}</strong> {{ selectedUser?.prenom }}
</span>
```

`structure` is the view structure object and `selectedUser` an object describing a user.

My code ALMOST works. The HTML tags are correctly replaced and any static or dynamic content belonging to the `structure` object is correctly re-rendered in the HTML tag that was generated from the directive.

However, if I use an other object to populate the view, it does not work. The variables belonging to it are not re-rendered.

Nevertheless, I am confused by something that can be illustrated by the following example.

Notice the 2 console.log() in the directive's `updateTemplate()`method.

The first one outputs `<strong class="ml-1">THE SELECTED USER'S NAME</strong> THE SELECTED USER'S FIRST NAME</span>` (object).

The second however, outputs `<strong class="ml-1"></strong></span>` (html).

But only when the template variables belong to an object that is not `structure`.

Why is that? And how could I achieve what I want? Is it at all possible with Angular?

Comment: I don't get what the essential point is of this question. How is this `innerHTML` and `replaceChild()` stuff related to this question? Are you aware that Angular doesn't care in any way about HTML added this way? 
 What or where is the template mentioned in the title?

Comment: I agree with @GünterZöchbauer. Angular is supposed to create a SPA. What you're doing here is basically what PHP does : sending the pages to the user. Only that you are using an even more complicated way to do that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Of course I am aware that Angular doesn't care about HTML added with innerHTML. And I must confess I am not too sure how to ask the question correctly. What I am trying to achieve and can almost do, is replace "placeholder" HTML tags with JSON "generated" HTML tags.

Comment: So what part of your approach is causing you troubles? Finding the placeholder?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: The part that is causing me trouble is how do I access the generated content of the tag (ie. what the template outputs) and inject it into the new tag I created.

Comment: @trichetriche: I disagree. How does this approach break SPA? All I am doing is telling Angular what type of HTML tag I want to render. Imagine for example you wanted to generate a form based on JSON.

Comment: Somehow it seems you try to mess with `{{ selectedUser?.nom }}` with imperative code. Is that right?

Comment: @Benjamin if I wanted to generate a form based on JSON, I would use the reactive forms that are made for that. What I'm saying is that you should not send the page structure to your SPA, but instead your data, and make the view corresponding to the data in your SPA.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: correct. If I use for example {{ row?.attribute }} instead, it works like a charm.

Comment: I'd suggest to make your question more clear. You have 3 nested `*ngIf` that don't seem to be relevant to the question but add tons of complexity if someone tries to understand what the question is about. I also think it would help to make more clear what the expected behavior is (what should the DOM look like after X happened).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I don't have any `*ngIf`s… But I agree the question is a rather complex one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `*ngFor`s. "the question is a rather complex one" - seems some if it unnecessarily